# connect to AD using anonymous binding and search a user DN

Tags: java, active-directory

I am trying to connect to AD using `Anonymous binding` and do some operations like search a user DN using CN, find mail id etc ....

Here is the code:

```
public class TestADAnanymousConnection {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
            "ldap://localhost:389/dc=myad,dc=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
    DirContext ctx;
    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    System.out.println(ctx.lookup("cn=Administrator"));
}
```

}

It shows error message as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: **In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection**., data 0, v1db1 remaining name 'cn=Administrator'
    at line System.out.println(ctx.lookup("cn=Administrator"));
```

Can somebody please let me know whether I missed anything in the code?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [What is LDAP anonymous binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644490/what-is-ldap-anonymous-binding) & [Binding and unbinding -  Apache LDAP API](https://directory.apache.org/api/user-guide/2.2-binding-unbinding.html)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot. Anonymous binding is only possible for quering root DN. That's it.

Comment: Can you please let me how you query the base dn?